# How do you access a dynamically built select box's selected value with jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html

Is there a way to get the selected value (or text, or index) of a select box that the server fills (using ASP.NET) in the client?  I've tried $("#ID").val() - but the only time that works is when I continue to another page and then go back.  Even then, the value that is returned is the previously selected value - if the user changes the selection, it's not registered unless they leave the page and go back.  Go easy on me, I'm new at this...

Update:  Tried using a regular html select, same issue (just with a populated entry).  Let me elaborate on what I'm trying to do:  in a separate page, I'm getting results for an autocomplete search box.  The select boxes are for filters.  Naturally, if the user selects a filter, I don't want to suggest items that are no longer valid.  I'm looking for the keys in the ProcessRequest method of the page that contains autocomplete info.

```
public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string respString;
        string qsKey = "q";
        Customer searchCust = Session[Data.Selected_Customer] as Customer;
        Dictionary<string, string> qsDict = context.Request.QueryString.ToDictionary(qsKey);
```

Shouldn't I get the results (for instance '&ID=foo' on the last line @ context.Request.QueryString?

Comment: Do I understand this correctly - you're creating a new URL in javascript that includes the selected value? If that's right, could you post the exact javascript that creates the URL, and the markup that defines your select element, as it's output by ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the actual selected item itself:

```
$("#ID option:selected");
```

Comment: You also need to add .text() if you want the value of course.

Comment: There progress - now the url is "&ID=" (using .text()) instead of "&ID=null" - any thoughts?

Comment: I just ran a test and it worked fine for me. Are you including # with the id of the element? example:  $("#myElementId option:selected").text();

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that 'ID' is really the id of the select box ? been awhile since i used asp.net but i remember it mucked with identifiers a lot

Comment: #ID is a filler, but both name and id are correct when I view the page source.

Answer (score 0):

I use the code (below) to manipulate an ASP.NET generated select box.  Within the code I obtain the value of the original select box (item).  Also consider using the .text() function.

```
    var setValue = function(item){  
        //if value isn't already selected, postback
            if(input.value != item.text())
                if(select.attr('onchange'))
                    eval(select[0].attributes['onchange'].nodeValue);

            //set input box value
            $(input).val(item.text());
            $(input).removeClass('empty');

            //select original ASP.NET select value (hidden)
            select.val(item.text());

            $(lookup).hide();

            //show type if present
            $('.selectType').show();
    };
```

Hope this helps.